# Custom cursor not working?

Tags: html, css, image, custom-cursor

I have a slideshow with navigation that is applied when he user hovers and clicks on the right hand side and the left hand side of the page.

For some reason when I set the cursor to be pointer or w-resize they work fine but as soon as I apply my own image like below they don't work.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas why this might be happening. I have made sure the image is below 30px x 30px as I have seen this mentioned as an issue but I can't seem to get it to work.

Below is the css I'm using…

CSS

```
#previous {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 55px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: url(images/crosscursor.png), auto;
}

#next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px 55px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: url(images/crosscursor.png), auto;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Your relative path might be wrong?

Comment: check your console to see if any "not found" errors are visible

Comment: I think you should go UP one level in the path by `../` to reach the image folder (assuming that the CSS file is in a different folder than images).

Comment: Thats where I went wrong my path to my images folder. It's always something so simple that you miss! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cursor: url('/images/crosscursor.png'), auto;`

Answer (score 0):

**try this work fine:**

```
#previous {
    cursor:auto;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: url(images/crosscursor.png) 6 6 auto;
}

#next {
    cursor:auto;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: url(images/crosscursor.png) 6 6 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROD
AS
    V_Cnt NUMBER;
    I_TableName VARCHAR2(30):='BANK';
    PK_Column_Name VARCHAR2(30):='BANK_ID';
    I_PK_Value NUMBER:=1;
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||I_TableName||' WHERE '||PK_Column_Name||'='||I_PK_Value INTO V_Cnt;      
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi '||V_Cnt);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```